# Installing rbenv apt-get vs git checkout

Tags: apt, ruby

I'm finding confliccting advice on how to install rbenv (and ruby) in recent ubuntu versions (13.10).

Many guides suggest cloning from git, and updating bashrc etc. For example [this guide on gorails.com](http://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/13.10).

Others suggest just using apt, with the universe repository enabled. For example [this guide from install lion](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/saucy/universe/r/rbenv/install.html).

What's the difference, and pros and cons of each technique?

Comment: Well I'm none the wiser, but in the end I used the manual process, which seems to be working ok. If anyone has any insight, I'd still like to hear it.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 is no longer supported. Upgrade to 14.04

Comment: @user308564 But it was when the question was asked :) More seriously, does askubuntu retire questions about outdated versions?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you value being on the bleeding edge or stability. If you're using rbenv to manage an existing codebase running on a lot of production servers, apt-get is a good choice. If you want to be sure you can run the latest version of Ruby, git clone is probably the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

I used both guides in the past and honestly is the same, on one you do a little more typing or Copy and Paste but it is the same thing.